# Class cast exception in FrameLayout when am trying to change the order of views in layout xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

Here is my layout file

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/document_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/load_document_progress"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_btn"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/start_btn_txt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:onClick="updatePresentationId"
        android:background="@drawable/border_radius"/>



</FrameLayout>
```

This is working. But when I have to change the order of the elements. I will get **ClassCastException**. Here is my my logcat trace.

> 12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start              activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.zoho.showmote/com.zoho.showmote.android.activity.ShowDocuments}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.ProgressBar 12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 12-24
>   18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-24
>   18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-24 18:33:58.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 12-24
>   18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-24
>   18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-24 18:33:58.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 12-24
>   18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-24 18:33:58.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2089): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ProgressBar
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   com.zoho.showmote.android.activity.ShowDocuments.getAllViews(ShowDocuments.java:50)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   com.zoho.showmote.android.activity.ShowDocuments.onCreate(ShowDocuments.java:39)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 12-24
>   18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   12-24 18:33:58.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):   ... 11 more

And here is my **Activity** code

```
public void getAllViews()
{
    **progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.load_document_progress);**
    startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.document_id);
    userName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.userNameTv);
    presentationName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.presentation_name);
}
```

I got the error at 1st line of this method. I am changing the visibilities of views in Asyntask's onPreExecute and onPostExecute(). Please help what I did wrong here?

Comment: `.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ProgressBar`  means you are trying to cast Button to ProgressBar somewhere in code so check declaration of startButton button

Comment: progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.load_document_progress);
startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start_btn);                                 Nothing wrong with the declaration. It was the eclipse problem. When I clean the project error has disappeared.

Comment: What do you mean by change the order? Change the xml layout between runs, or change it while the app is running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you the change the order of Widgets. Clean your project and build it again.

In the Eclipse Menu, Project --->Clean

Comment: Incredible. Who might have thought it? Thanks!

Comment: This is also an issue in Android Studio! And the solution is brilliant.